# How to get a password as a char[] rather than a String in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Okay after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8881376/4801219) I have got the idea that its better to store the password in an array rather than String.

So when getting the password from a request parameter in a servlet's `doPost` method, wont that cause a security risk, because the password is retrieved as an actual String ?

Is that the most secure way of getting the password in a servlet ? Or can I use char[] to get my password ?

Comment: Not sure what your point is. What exactly are you defending against? If the password safely made it to the server-side, what specific concern are you trying to mitigate? The answer you linked even says that the best you can do is *reduce* the (remote) risk of memory-probing. Up until the point where you call `getParameter` or whatever, the password and all parameters, are represented as Strings. As at the point you're fretting about security, it's probably pointless

Comment: We send our keystore passwords as Base-64 encoded and encrypted Strings.  Whether we use a `String` or a `char[]` is not so important.

Comment: While this is a security concern against a particular attack, using char[] here won't help you - it will, at best, make the window of opportunity smaller. It's certainly not on the priority list of concerns you should be worried about.

Comment: Either char[] or String, the password would be visible in request content, if you don't use HTTPS to securely communicate data between client and server.

Comment: @kolossus What if the server side memory was somehow dumped ? I believe if I am not mistaken vulnerabilities like HeartBleed would allow us to do this. So if it was a char[] I could overwrite it after the password has been read. Rather than keeping the String object in memory.

Comment: The idea of a eraseable password type is good only as long as you do not have to use any string-processing APIs. As soon as you have to convert it you lose all the advantages.